# how to create my own ros controller

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  I want to create cartesian position controller, but I did not find any documentation or example code.
I've seen that page http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control it didn't help me.
I use the kinetic distribution.
Does someone know how to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278477/how-to-create-my-own-ros-controller/) by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During a workshop a few years ago, we implemented a simple ros_control cartesian velocity controller taking Twist messages as input. While not exactly what you're asking for, it should provide some useful inspiration: https://github.com/johmau85/tedusar_manipulation/blob/master/tedusar_cartesian_controller/src/cartesian_controller.cpp

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0